# Are old question without answers useful?

Tags: discussion

If an old question has no answers and no comments, does it matter if it was upvoted and viewed?

I mean useful to anybody. Several times on looking up a problem, I have found it as a question without an answer. It didn't help me.

Comment: useful to whom?

Comment: Read http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/259214

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned by Nicael, checks are already made to **automatically delete questions** that have a **certain criteria** of poor age, view count, and votes.  Questions that are old, unviewed, and/or poorly received in the right combination are considered non-useful and removed.  The exact calculation can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).

If you come across a question that is any of those things but still exists, it simply is mathematically determined to **not be useless enough to warrant deletion by this formula**.

Comment: [What should the system be deleting automatically that it already isn't?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262077/what-should-the-system-be-deleting-automatically-that-it-already-isnt)

Answer (score 5):

Sure.  If I run into the same problem and find the unanswered question, I don't get my answer but I do get to not spend the time assembling the question (which, depending on the problem, can be substantial).  Instead, I can:

- Improve the existing question (thus bringing it to people's attention again).
- Add a bounty to the existing question (ditto).
- Look to see if the asker asked on some other SE site after not getting an answer (longshot, but it happens).
- Decide that my problem is different enough that I should ask my own question, in which case I can reference the prior question and explain how mine is different.

If a question is old and hasn't gotten much attention (votes, views) it'll be auto-deleted eventually, so what I've said here applies to questions that survived the Roomba.